# Cannot import PublicKey from solana.publickey

Tags: python, websocket, solana, solana-py

I'm developing a tracking script using Python and the Solana.py, installed via pip. The script uses websocket subscriptions to notify me when something happens on the Solana blockchain. My first approach was to watch a specific account:

```
await websocket.account_subscribe(PublicKey('somekeyhere'))
```

But when doing ...

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
```

I get the following error:

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.publickey'
```

Solana.py is the latest version (0.31.0). I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and using Python 3.10.12.

I found a workaround, just using another subscription method, that does not need any parameters:

```
await websocket.logs_subscribe()
```

Then I analyze the output to my needs. That means, that I'm dealing with every single log on the Solana blockchains. It works, but it does not "feel right". And I would love to understand, what is going wrong when using the websocket.account_subscribe method.

Any suggestions?
Regards
Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on their github, it looks like what you need is Pubkey, not Publickey, taken from solders rather than solana. Have you tried this instead?

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
```

I haven't used their SDK before, so this might not solve your issue, but it was something I noted given your issue.

Ref: [solana.py Github](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/tests/integration/test_websockets.py)

Comment: Yes, tried that out already. Just getting another weird error:

await websocket.account_subscribe(Pubkey('somekeyhere'))
ValueError: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 44)

Comment: Thank you for pushing me into the right direction!

The right format - when using solders is:

from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

And then:

await websocket.account_subscribe(Pubkey.from_string('somekeyhere'))

Answer (score 0):

Are you having any issues when importing:

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
```

I am trying to import solders but keep getting "could not resolve module not found" even though I have installed solders and solana

how did you overcome this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As described above. See my second comment to Brians suggestion.

Comment: Can you link me to it? thanks for the response